# What does padding do in 2d convolution of images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, signal-processing, convolution

Having two images , A and B of sizes `n`-by-`m` , `k`-by-`l`.
When doing convolution via Fourier transform , it is said that we have to pad with zeros the signals. What does this exactly mean?
When I get `ifft2(A, B, n+k-1, m+l-1)` its like padded is done? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see an option for `ifft2` to take 4 numerical arguments as you have used it: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft2.html Are you trying to do convolution or inverse Fourier transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To zero-pad, you must increase the size of A and B until they are both n+k-1, m+l-1 (or greater) in size by adding rows and columns of zeros to these array/matrix variables.  If you don't zero-pad, the convolution effect will wrap around (top-to-bottom and left-to-right) thus messing up your result (unless you actually want this circular convolution wrap-around effect).